# need help in ATM Alloy

Tags: alloy

I am trying to model that, ATM system which provides an available amount of money after authenticates that the card and pin are correct, otherwise,  the amount of money is not provided.
Also if the card is incorrect, it will be rejected
if the pin is not correct , it will be rejected

In the first model, there is a counterexample appeared and I fixed it in the second model below.

My question is, I just wonder if my model is fine?
and solving the counterexample is correct ?
Thanks

The model with counterexample :

```
module ATM_Sys
one sig Enter_Card {}
abstract sig ATM_Operation {}
one sig  Reject_Pin, Reject_Card, Provides_Amount,Dont_Provides_Amount extends ATM_Operation{}


sig ATM {
card : lone Card , 
userOp :  Enter_Card lone -> card, 
AtmOp:   userOp-> lone ATM_Operation  
} 

sig Card
{
pin : one Int,
balance: one Int
}

fact   {all  crd,pn:Card| crd.balance >0 && pn.pin >0 } 

pred Start[atm,atm':ATM,crd:Card]
{
atm.userOp=Enter_Card->crd &&
atm'.card=crd && atm'.card=atm.card && TypePin [atm,atm']
}

pred TypePin[atm,atm':ATM]
{
 atm'.card.pin=Int && atm'.card.pin=atm.card.pin implies SelectAmount[atm,atm']
}

pred SelectAmount[atm,atm':ATM]
{
 atm'.card.balance=Int  implies atm'.AtmOp=atm.userOp->Provides_Amount
}

assert ATM_System
{all atm,atm':ATM,crd:Card|
Start[atm,atm',crd]  =>( 
atm'.card!=atm.card  && atm'.AtmOp=atm.userOp->Reject_Card ||
atm'.card.pin!=atm.card.pin &&atm'.AtmOp=atm.userOp->Reject_Pin || 
atm'.card.balance!=atm.card.balance  && atm'.AtmOp=atm.userOp->Dont_Provides_Amount )
}

check ATM_System for 1
run Start
```

---

The model without counterexample :

```
module ATM_Sys
one sig Enter_Card {}
abstract sig ATM_Operation {}
one sig  Reject_Pin, Reject_Card, Provides_Amount,Dont_Provides_Amount extends ATM_Operation{}


sig ATM {
card : lone Card , 
userOp :  Enter_Card lone -> card, 
AtmOp:   userOp-> lone ATM_Operation  
} 

sig Card
{
pin : one Int,
balance: one Int
}

fact   {all  crd,pn:Card| crd.balance >0 && pn.pin >0 } 

pred Start[atm,atm':ATM,crd:Card]
{
atm.userOp=Enter_Card->crd &&
atm'.card=crd && atm'.card=atm.card && TypePin [atm,atm']
}

pred TypePin[atm,atm':ATM]
{
 atm'.card.pin=Int && atm'.card.pin=atm.card.pin implies SelectAmount[atm,atm']
}

pred SelectAmount[atm,atm':ATM]
{
 atm'.card.balance=Int  implies atm'.AtmOp=atm.userOp->Provides_Amount
}

assert ATM_System
{all atm,atm':ATM,crd:Card|
Start[atm,atm',crd]  =>( 
atm'.card!=atm.card  => atm'.AtmOp=atm.userOp->Reject_Card ||
atm'.card.pin!=atm.card.pin =>atm'.AtmOp=atm.userOp->Reject_Pin || 
atm'.card.balance!=atm.card.balance  => atm'.AtmOp=atm.userOp->Dont_Provides_Amount )
}

check ATM_System for 1
run Start
```

Also, when I fixed the counterexample, I noticed that, under any number of 
scopes, there is still no counterexample . Is that correct ?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest editing the question and making it more specific. Try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: The problem is, I am new in Alloy and need to understand how can I sure that my model is correct please ?

Comment: your model is correct if it specifies what you meant to specify, How can we be sure that it specifies what you meant to specify if you don't tell us PRECISELY what you meant to specify ? :)

Comment: adding to @bilboulboulbil 's statement, this is what we call validation. A valid model is one that represents what you wanted it to represent. There is no way to PROVE that a model is valid. However, you can improve your confidence in the model by testing it with predicates and assertions.